# How do I export a chart as a picture from MS Access 2019

Tags: ms-access, charts, export

I am porting a dashboard app from Access 2013 to 2019 and I cannot find the way to export charts as pictures.  I've recreated the charts on forms using the new chart engine but I can't get any method to work.

I used:

```
Set oleGrf = Forms("zf_" & GRFile$)!Graph1.Object
oleGrf.Export "U:\datasource\dashboards\cwgraphs\" & GRFile$ & ".PNG", "PNG"
```

Can anyone point me at an example of some code that does it please?

Answer (score 0):

I use Access 2010. This works for me:

```
    Dim grpApp As Object
    Set grpApp = Nothing
    Set grpApp = Me.Graph1.Object

    grpApp.Export "C:\Users\June\TestJHB.jpg"
    Me.Graph1.Locked = False
    Me.Graph1.Enabled = True

    Set grpApp = Nothing
    Me.Graph1.Action = acOLEClose
    Me.Graph1.Locked = True
    Me.Graph1.Enabled = False
```

Comment: Yes, it works on older versions, thanks.  I am looking for code that works on Access 2019.

Comment: Sorry, all I can find is a statement that ModerChart properties and settings would be available to VBA, but no code examples.